# Duplicate rows and incorrect indicators in merged DataFrame with Pandas merge

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-merge

### The date & function is:

- 2 same DF namely `left_df` and `right_df`:

```py
pd.DataFrame({'Column1': ['dummy_text1'],
              'Column2': [''],
              'Column3': [''],
              'Column4': ['dummy_text2'],
              'Column5': [''],
              'Column6': ['Dummy Role 1']
              })
```

- the function

```py
left_df.merge(right_df, 
              on=['Column1', 'Column2', 'Column3', 'Column4', 'Column5', 'Column6'], 
              how='outer', 
              indicator=True)
```

### **The question is:**

the result contains two rows, one as 'left_only' and one as 'right_only', instead of a single row with 'both' as indicator.

#### Other info.:

I have already tried the following steps to address the issue:

- Checked for leading/trailing whitespaces in the merge columns, but there are none.
- Verified that there are no duplicates in either DataFrame based on the merge columns.
- Used `drop_duplicates()` with `inplace=True` and `keep=False` on both DataFrames before the merge.
- Ensured that the merge columns have the same data types in both DataFrames.

Edit:

Sharing code snippet:
I forgot to mention this part, this is to resolve case of the values:

```py
left_df['Column1_U'] = left_df['Column1'].copy()
left_df['Column6_U'] = left_df['Column6'].copy()
right_df['Column1_U'] = right_df['Column1'].copy()
right_df['Column6_U'] = right_df['Column6'].copy()
```

this is the rest of the code:

```py
columns_to_exclude = ['Column1_U', 'Column6_U']

left_df = left_df.apply(lambda s: s.str.lower() if s.name not in columns_to_exclude else s)
right_df = right_df.apply(lambda s: s.str.lower() if s.name not in columns_to_exclude else s)

merged_df = merge(left = left_df
                ,right = right_df
                ,on=['Column1', 'Column2', 'Column3', 'Column4', 'Column5', 'Column6']
                ,how='outer'
                ,indicator=True)
```

but the output that i'm getting is this:
Column1,Column2,Column3,Column4,Column5,Column6,Column1_U_x,Column6_U_x,Column1_U_y,Column6_U_y,_merge
dummy_text1,,,dummy_text1,,dummy role 1,Dummy_text1,Dummy Role 1,,,left_only
dummy_text1,,,dummy_text1,,dummy role 1,,,Dummy_text1,Dummy Role 1,right_only

Comment: Your example code gives me one row with `both` as the `_merge` value.

Comment: Maybe it's some kind of bug on my machine or some data type issue, although I checked and both dataframes have all columns as object

Comment: Does it happen if you start a fresh python session and run your example? What version of pandas do you have? `print(pd.__version__)`

Comment: I get both when merged as well. Pandas 1.5.3

Comment: Versions: Pandas: 1.5.3, python: 3.10.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is solved. The issue turned out to be with `NULL` value and `''`, both these dataframes were getting created from SQL tables and in the query I was using `ISNULL(Column, '')` as Column in one and `NULL` AS Column in the other. Turns out after doing `dataframe.fillna('')`, it was treating the '' differently between both dataframes, after I updated the queries the issue was resolved.